# Quads snapping up or down when displacement is animated

Tags: animation, displacement

I am trying to make a 80's style grid mountain valley animation with the scene slightly animated by a noise texture displacement.

However when some deformed faces cross a certain point they "snap" either up or down creating a very distracting and bad looking effect.

I have made the initial mountains by applying a noise texture to a plain and modifying it to create a valley path for the camera which resulted in some faces being distorted or "bent" by having two opposing vertices below the other ones, this creates a jumping or snapping effect when the displacement makes the geometry cross the threshold of the "bend" being in the opposite direction.

Is there any way i can fix this? Like, disabling the snapping, or making it always face one direction without manually readjusting 150k+ faces?

Comment: What about using triangles instead of quads? Also do you have smooth shading turned on and autosmooth disabled?

Comment: I tried using trianbles, it helps but then all of the squares in the grid have an additional line through the middle and tht's not the effect i'm looking for ;p
I just enabled smooth shading, it was previously off as well as autosmooth and doing a test render with smooth shading enabled and autosmooth disabled.

@edit: faces are still snapping with smooth shading on

Answer (score 0):

I have converted my mesh into triangles and used this to wireframe it instead:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=67Q2Z4vVrMI&t=588s
It seems to have resolved the issue.